# Send data to a Discord webhook

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, webhooks, discord

Without using the requests module, how can I send messages to a Discord webhook?
I have tried following code:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'webhook url'
values = {"username": "Bot", "text": "This is a test message."}

data = json.dumps(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

This returns following error:

```
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: This means the app you are using is unauthorized to make any webhooks. You may need to get the token before making any requests.

Comment: The only thing I am provided by Discord when making a webhook is the webhook url @SubhrajyotiDas

Comment: What is the url that you are trying ?

Comment: Its a discord webhook url with the format https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/<server ID>/<...>

Answer (score 5):

You can send the message to a Discord webhook.

1. make a discord webhook with this [tutorial](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks).
2. Then, use the `discord.Webhook.from_url` method to fetch a Webhook object from the URL Discord gave you.
3. Use the `discord.Webhook.send` method to send a message using the `webhook`.

if you're using version 2 of [discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/), this snippet will work for you:

```
from discord import SyncWebhook

webhook = SyncWebhook.from_url("your-url")
webhook.send("Hello")
```

if you're not using version 2 you can use this snippet:

```
import requests
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter

webhook = Webhook.from_url("youre-url", adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
webhook.send("Hello")
```

Comment: Can you add references?
It is not clear which `discord` package you are referencing, or what additional options it may have.

Comment: add link to the correct package

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not correct - according to the [Discord API documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook), it should look like this:

```py
values = {
    'username': 'Bot',
    'content': 'your message here'
}
```

Please note that one of `content`, `file` or `embeds` is required. Otherwise the API will not accept your request.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is the following steps:

1. Make a webhook in the desired Discord channel.
2. use the `discord.Webhook.from_url` method to fetch a Webhook object from the URL Discord gave you.
3. use the `discord.Webhook.send` method to send a message.

another option is to use discord.py (v2) like this:

```
from discord import SyncWebhook

webhook = SyncWebhook.from_url("url-here")
webhook.send("Hello World")
```